# JavaScript - unable to add JSON values into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JSON file with informations of a lot of characters, but I only need one specific information of 5 characters and put the info into an array, but when I try to access data in the array it returns undefined. The needed info of each character is an array.

The rough format of JSON file:

```
{Version: "10.2.1"
 data: {
   a: {neededInfo:["An array of needed info"], otherInfo:"any other info"}
   b: {neededInfo:["An array of needed info"], otherInfo:"any other info"}
   ...
 }
}
```

Below is my first attempt:

```
//a given array with character names
team = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
var info = [];

for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
    const name = team[i]

    fetch('characters.json')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => response.data)
        .then((response) => {
            info.push(response[name]["neededInfo"])
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
}
```

when I console.log(info) it gave me this:
[console.log(info)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbEce.png)

I researched and suspected that it might be something related to async/await, so I changed the code to this:

```
//a given array with character names
team = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
var info = [];

const fetching = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('characters.json')
    const responded = await response.json()
    const data = await responded.data
    for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
        const name = team[i]
        info.push(data[name]["neededInfo"])
    }
}
```

This worked as well, but it produces the same array as the first attempt. I am unable to get array elements via index, and the length of the array is 0. Any reasons why is this happening?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The first approach makes rather little sense, because you are fetching the exact same JSON multiple times, once for each letter – that is nothing but redudant.

Comment: With the second, `response[name]` appears to access the wrong variable. You assigned the `data` object from your JSON to the variable `data` before, so _that_ is what you should access with the dynamic `name` now. Btw. `const data = await responded.data` – await looks superfluous to me here, there is nothing async about `responded`.

Comment: I second @CBroe. Just change response to data in the info.push line and it should work. And remove the unnecessary await.

Comment: Instead of the for-loop you could also use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `info = team.map(name => data[name]["neededInfo"])`

Comment: @CBroe sorry that was really careless of me. However even though I got the final array, it is still the same outcome as my first attempt - I couldn't access via index (such as info[0]) and the length of the array is 0. Do you have any idea why is this happening? Is it again something related to async/await?

Comment: Can you please log the content of `responded` to console, and see what that gets you?